# Why Should I use this "while" expression here? And what does THAT expression mean?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I write a program that asks the user how many cars to catalog.The program uses new to create a dynamic array of that many car structures. Next, it should prompt the user to input the make and year information for each structure.

However, I missed "WHILE" expression before. And the program directly run to the end. The result was following:

[image]

And the expected result should be

[image]

**What problems occurred? And what should I do when I need to alternate reading strings with numeric data?**

Here are my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 using std::string;
// create car structure
struct car
{
   string make;
   int year;
};

int main()
{
   using std::cout;
   using std::cin;
   using std::endl;

   int num;
   cout << "How many cars do you wish to catalog? ";
   cin >> num;
   while (cin.get() != '\n')
      ;

// create a dynamic array
   car * catalog = new car [num];

//store
   for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
   {
      cout << "Car #" << i + 1 << ":\n";
      cout << "Please enter the make: ";
      getline(cin, catalog[i].make);
      cout << "Please enter the year made: ";
      cin >> catalog[i].year;
      while (cin.get() != '\n')
          ;

    }

//display
  cout << "Here is your collection: \n";
  for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
  {
     cout << catalog[i].year << "  " << catalog[i].make << endl;
  }

  delete [] catalog;

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: That `while` statement is a way of skipping to the end of the input line.

Comment: Probably save a bit of time (but not typing) with `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')`

Comment: Thank you!! @Captain Obvlious

Comment: Thank you!! @user4581301

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0):

When you input something to `std::cin`, there always will be trailing `'\n'`, because you end the input with Enter key.
When you invoke `cin >> num`, `std::cin` will only extract the number, not the trailing `'\n'`. So after that, the trailing `'\n'` will be still present in the input buffer.
And when you call `getline` after that, it will read (and discard) that `'\n'`.

My suggestion: Do not mix `std::cin.operator >>` and `getline`.
Even though both will extract and discard the leading whitespaces, `getline` will always regard `'\n'` as the end of the input, and will extract and discard it.
In the other hand, `std::cin.operator >>` won't read that `'\n'`, and will regard it as just a whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
While(cin.get()!='\n');
```

This line of code eliminates newline character from the input buffer.

But the question why?

Because of this line

```
getline(cin, catalog [i].make);
```

What is the problem in that line?

The problem is here, getline() function reads content from input buffer till it finds '\n'. When you execute the above code

```
cin>>catalog[i].made
```

You will type number and press enter. But in this case '\n' will be remained in the buffer. If '\n' is still in the buffer then getline() function will read the '\n' and it'll assume that you have typed input. But no data is actually read.

So don't use getline() instead

```
cin>>catalog[I].make;
```

Comment: Actually in this line I want to type string and getline() method probably can read '\n' , right?

Comment: I know what you mean. The problem occurred AT THE cin >> num [ENTER]    Thank you very much!!!